# Will my Borderlands 2 campaign be ruined if I play matchmaking?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands 1 I needed help on a boss, so I tried to find some people to help me in matchmaking. When I found the game I needed, I connected but they were playing something else so I exited. But when I got to my single player campaign, **my story skipped through half the game!** I'm so afraid that if I do matchmaking in Borderlands 2, my single-player will be ruined! Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to multiplayer it wont ruin your game, because unless quests are completed while you are playing(those quests have to be unlocked in your game too) your progress won't change.

What you would have to be aware of is that spoilers are a high probability. your best option is to open your game to multiplayer and then you won't be transported to different parts of the game.

Also be aware that if you are stuck on a certain section don't get annoyed if there is no one online wanting to do that quest. Hop on a forum or in chat with friends and ask the internet if there is anyone that can help you, then set up a private game with them.

I hope this has cleared things up and has helped.

Flaunting

Answer (score 0):

If you join someone else. your own campaign will not be affected. However, you will get an option to skip any quests you have already completed once you go back to single player. Just say no if you don't want to skip anything.